# How do I scrape live updating website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: web-scraping

I have been trying to extract live data from worldometer.com(https://www.worldometers.info/), particularly the health section data. I was able to extract the title (example:'Communicable disease deaths today' but I cannot extract the live data(numbers). Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: There are APIs that Worldometers uses to get their information. You can try to access those APIs and get information from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live data(numbers) is populated by JavaScript and you can grab it easily using automation tool something like selenium. Here is an example. Please just run the code.

Script:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

num  = soup.select_one('div#c49 > div > span.counter-number')
print(num.text)
```

Output:

```
2,134,658
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this. It worked